# Sub procedure that takes an argument as a user defined data type to add to data dictionary collection

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to learn how to work with dictionary collections that uses keys. I have a text file which has been delimited by a special character. Using the VBA Macro Recorder, I have learned how to remove consecutive delimiters as well as arranging the columns to prevent the text file coming in with headers in different places.

The data contains applicant information:

```
Name | Date       | State | University | Age
Ann  | 2015-01-14 | NY    | Boston     | 18
Bob  | 2015-02-11 | MA    | Stanford   | 17
```

The data is stored on a worksheet, for the sake of this example, on Sheet 1. Starting with the headers on row 1, col 1.

I created a user defined object called Applicant:

```
Type Applicant
    Name as String
    DateApp as Date
    State as String
    University as String
    Age as Double
End Type
```

I would like to create a data dictionary 'Applicants' collection to store each instance of Applicant. I am thinking something like this:

```
Public Sub add_applicant(prsPerson as Applicant)
```

Is there a way to do this? I understand the basics on using for/each loop to .add to a collection but I have only seen adding single entries being added to a dictionary collection. I would like to expand upon this and add components of the data type from the user defined object. I want single instance of Applicants collection to contain the data for exactly one applicant line.

Would I do something like this?

```
Dim prsPerson As Applicant
Set prsPerson = New Applicant
With prsPerson
    .Name = "Ann"
    .Age = 18
    .State = "NY"
    .Date = "2015-01-14"
    .University = "Boston"
End With

Applicants.Add Item:=prsPerson
```

How can I create a for loop that goes through the range block and add for each row, the value in the column (headers such as as Name, Age, State, etc) into the data collection for a given person using the Sub Procedure add_applicant(prsPerson as Applicant)?

How can I add a key to this? I want the key to be composed of Name. However Ann show up more than once in the data file because she can apply to different schools. Is this allowed? Because I also want to calculate how many times Ann applied etc.

Comment: You could consider changing your Type so that `University` is an array - you don't need to create multiple versions of the same person becaise they've applied to >1 school.  Also note that you're using a *Type* here, not a *Class*, so your applicant is still a "value type", and you don't use Set in that case.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described it doesn't sound like you need a dictionary but a collection of Applicants.  Collections has optional keys but keys are cleaner with Dictionarys.  Either way you can't have different objects for the same key though.  You can still loop through the collection and count the number of times Ann comes up.

I've had trouble (using Excel 2007) adding Types to collections though.  I get an error of 'Only user-defined types in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions'

You can create an array of Applicants though.

```
dim applicants() as Applicant
redim applicants(0 to 9) 'you may count rows here to get the number you expect to use.
```

Another alternative to the Type you created is a Class with all the same attributes.  There's lots of information out there on how to create a class so I won't go into that here.  They are similar to Types but have some differences and more functionality with greater complexity.

If you don't want to create a Class and still want to use a collection here's a possible method that uses dictionaries in a different way than you originally intended.  You end up with a collection of dictionaries.  If you create a class you only have to modified this slightly to change the dictionaries to your new class.

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Collection
    Dim d As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = 10 'Change this to fit your data

    Set c = New Collection
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
        d("Name") = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        d("Date") = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
        'etc
        c.Add d
        Set d = Nothing
    Next

    'to count Ann's applications
    Dim entry As Variant
    Dim appCount As Long

    For Each entry In c
        If entry("Name") = "Ann" Then
            appCount = appCount + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```